# imported createStackNavigator undefined

Tags: react-native, npm, redux, react-navigation, react-native-ios

I have a problem with importing my stack navigator in a react-native project. I am using the JSX syntax. Below I have posted information about the project that I hope is relevant to find a solution to this issue.

The following code does the import. It lies in a file called App.js

```js
import { AppNavigator } from '../navigation'
console.log(AppNavigator) // prints undefined
```

AppNavigator.js looks like the following:

```js
import { createStackNavigator } from 'react-navigation'
import StartScreen from '../screen/start-screen'

const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Start: {
    screen: StartScreen
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Start',
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
})

export default AppNavigator
```

I have simplified the router configuration (AppNavigator is a bit more complicated) to try and isolate the issue and I don't believe StartScreen is mucking things up. StartScreen.js has never failed before, but the "undefined issue" happened after I attempted to integrate redux with react navigation has described in: https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/redux-integration.html

Here is the project's package.json:

```js
{
  "name": "App",
  "version": "0.0.1",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node node_modules/react-native/local-cli/cli.js start",
    "test": "jest",
    "clean": "watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf ios/build/ && rm -rf android/build/ && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* rm package-lock.json && npm install && react-native link && npm start",
    "ios": "react-native run-ios"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "debounce": "^1.1.0",
    "deep-freeze": "0.0.1",
    "es6-promise": "^4.2.4",
    "event-emitter": "^0.3.5",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^2.2.1",
    "moment": "^2.22.1",
    "react": "16.3.1",
    "react-datepicker": "^1.5.0",
    "react-dom": "^16.4.1",
    "react-native": "^0.55.4",
    "react-native-calendar": "^0.13.1",
    "react-native-calendars": "^1.19.3",
    "react-native-collapsible": "^0.12.0",
    "react-native-elements": "^0.19.1",
    "react-native-form": "^2.1.2",
    "react-native-modal": "^6.1.0",
    "react-native-vector-icons": "^4.6.0",
    "react-navigation": "^2.5.5",
    "react-navigation-redux-helpers": "^2.0.2",
    "react-redux": "^5.0.7",
    "redux": "^4.0.0",
    "redux-form": "^7.4.2",
    "redux-logger": "^3.0.6",
    "redux-thunk": "^2.2.0"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "babel-jest": "22.4.3",
    "babel-preset-react-native": "4.0.0",
    "eslint": "^4.19.1",
    "eslint-plugin-react": "^7.10.0",
    "jest": "22.4.3",
    "react-test-renderer": "16.3.1",
    "standard": "^11.0.1"
  },
  "jest": {
    "preset": "react-native"
  }
}
```

I am running the project with Xcode 9.2 on a MacBook Mini (macOS Sierra 10.12.6)

My question is: What reasons could result in an import yielding undefined when the import "should work". I believe my syntax is correct . Is the reasons related to the build or linking. I have rebuilt the project several times, removed the App on the IOS simulator, and reinstalled it with Xcode. I have also run the following command:

```
"watchman watch-del-all && rm -rf node_modules/ && rm -rf ios/build/ && rm -rf android/build/ && rm -rf $TMPDIR/react-* rm package-lock.json && npm install && react-native link"
```

Comment: Welcome to SO! Great work documenting your issue. Since you asked for pointers... I noticed that you addressed your question to "Dear forum dwellers." SO is kind of like a forum, but different. I think in the FAQ somewhere it actually says "this is not a discussion forum." You don't need to address your question to anyone; just by posting it here, we know that it's a question you would like the community to answer. Not a big deal at all, it just stood out to me when I read your intro. :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You see this?

`import { AppNavigator } from '../navigation'`

Try this:

`import AppNavigator from '../navigation'`

This is because you're using `export default AppNavigator`. If you were setting out your *AppNavigator* with an export like this:

```
export const AppNavigator = createStackNavigator({
  Start: {
    screen: StartScreen
  }
}, {
  initialRouteName: 'Start',
  navigationOptions: {
    header: null
  }
})
```

Then your destructured (`import { AppNavigator } from '../navigation'`) would be correct.

Comment: Thanks for responding! Alright! I have made the change you recommended, but the fault still persists. Thoughts?

Comment: Okay, so does your console.log still throw undefined? Is the module definitely in the parent directory relevant to App.js?

Comment: Yes it is definitely correct. Difficult to say what the issue is at this point.

Comment: If I do "setTimeOut( () => { console.log(AppNavigator) }, 2000)" the correct output is shown. The Navigator is small here. Why does it take so long for it to load?

Answer (score 0):

StartScreen.js contained an incorrect import , which caused the import of StartScreen in AppNavigator.js to become undefined.